# I can't install " npm install semantic-ui-react semantic-ui-css", what should I do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, semantic-ui

```
C:\reactcamp\camp-project> npm install semantic-ui-react semantic-ui-css
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: camp-project@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from semantic-ui-react@2.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/semantic-ui-react
npm ERR!   semantic-ui-react@"^2.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\zekis\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zekis\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-01T18_07_14_536Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TLDR:**
`semantic-ui-react@2.1.2` is [incompatible with React 18](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/4354). As a workaround, you can downgrade your application to **React 17**.

#### While resolving: camp-project@0.1.0

```
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
```

Those first three lines indicate that npm identified **React 18** as your project's dependency.

#### Could not resolve dependency

```
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from semantic-ui-react@2.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/semantic-ui-react
npm ERR!   semantic-ui-react@"^2.1.2" from the root project
```

These 3 lines list `semantic-ui-react`'s peer dependency, meaning it expects your project to have either **React 16.8** or **React 17** as dependency.

#### Fix the upstream dependency conflict

There are two ways to address this conflict:

1. Downgrade your project to **React 17** using `npm install react@17`
2. Override `semantic-ui-react`'s using yarn's [Selective Resolution feature](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/4105). Inside your package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
    "semantic-ui-react/react": "^18.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Should be resolved in `semantic-ui-react@2.1.3`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [article](https://dev.to/lowla/create-react-app-with-a-previous-version-of-react-4g03) it helped me solved the same problem when i wanted to install `semantic-ui` with `react 18` it will probably help you with other frameworks that doesn't compatible with react 18